# PHP - If in_array

Tags: php, arrays

I am working with CodeIgniter and have created a custom form preferences custom config. In that I have an array that is as follows:

```
Array
(
  [1] => Category 1
  [2] => Category 2
  [3] => Category 3
  [4] => Category 4
  [5] => Category 5   
)
```

I am passing that to the view as the var `$service_categories` what I'd then like to do is match it to the "value" that is in the database. I.E 5. If it matches then show `Category 5` in the view. At the moment I am just showing `5` - This is no good to the user.

The variable `$service->service_category` is a number.

The var `service` produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [service_id] => 3
        [organisation_id] => 2
        [service_name] => Edited Service 3
        [service_description] => This is service 3 provided by
        [service_category] => 5
        [service_metadata] => Metadata for service 3 - Edited
        [service_cost] => 22.00
        [service_active] => active
    )
)
```

My current PHP for this is as follows:

```php
if (in_array($service->service_category, $service_categories))
{
   echo "Exists";
}
```

However, the `Exists` is not showing in the view. It is showing nothing at all.

Am I doing something wrong with the `in_array` method?

Comment: can you post `var_dump($service)` here ?

Comment: Sure I've added it to the question

Comment: On a side note: this is a very good way to ask a question, the information is thorough enough :)

Comment: the variable is a number but your comparing it with text 'Category 5'

Comment: is the index the ID or just the index of the array (as there is no 0)?

Comment: Hi, Yes the index is the ID, There is no 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`in_array()` checks if a *value* exists in the array. So in_array('Category 1', $service_categories) would work.

However, to check if a key is present in an array, you can use:

```
if(array_key_exists($service->service_category, $service_categories)) {
    echo "Exists";
}
```

I think, this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Brilliant, Thats bringing it back. I'll try working out how to match the names up now

Comment: `isset()` could also be used. However, as `isset()` checks if the key exists **and** the value is not null, I would prefer using `array_key_exists()`, as it only checks for key existence.

Answer (score 4):

> The variable : $service->service_category is a number.

And that precisely is the problem: your testing to see if "5" is equal to "Category 5", which it is obviously not. Simplest solution would be to prepend the "5" with "Category ":

```
<?php
$category = 'Category ' . $service->service_category;

if (in_array($category, $service_categories)) {
   echo "Exists";
}
```

**EDIT**: If you want to check if the array *key* exists (because '5' => 'Category 5'), this could be achieved with isset( ) or array_key_exists.

```
<?php
if (array_key_exists ($service->service_category, $service_categories )) {
   echo "Exists";
}

// does the same:
if (isset ($service_categories[service->service_category] )) {
   echo "Exists";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) is the function you might search.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (isset($service_categories[$service->service_category])) {
   echo "Exists";
}
```